# In the New Testament, What is the Origin of "Believe In" and "Believe Into"?

Tags: john, word-study, cultural-analysis, figure-of-speech

Is there any Extra-Biblical source, (in Classical Greek, or Semitic sources), or a syntactical rule, behind the construction: **["πιστεύων ἐν" and "πιστεύων εἰς" + "Some Leader"]***  — Or, is this phenomena unique to New Testament texts?

> **John 3:16, NASB -** 16 “For God so loved the world, that He gave His only begotten Son, that whoever believes in Him ***[πιστεύων εἰς αὐτὸν]*** shall not perish, but have eternal life.

---

**Notes:**

The argument, that this construction forms figures-of-speech, (Metonymy, etc), in the form [Verb + ἐν or εἰς + "Some Leader"], seems to be supported by the repetitive use of two specific forms in the New Testament, ("***Believe In/Into***", and "**Baptized Into**") :

> **Romans 6:3, NASB -** Or do you not know that all of us who have been baptized into Christ Jesus ***[ἐβαπτίσθημεν εἰς Χριστὸν Ἰησοῦν]*** have been baptized into His death ***[εἰς τὸν θάνατον αὐτοῦ ἐβαπτίσθημεν]***?

1. πιστεύω is understood to mean "Trust".
2. New Testament use is complicated, by a lack of apparent use in Classical Greek.
3. The New Testament appears to distinguish the use of the Greek word, "to Trust/Believe", from another, which takes a preposition, coupled with "Into/εἰς".

---

### Other Similar Questions

The Source/Precedent issue is distinct from issues raised in other questions:

1. [The word 'believe' in John 3:15-16](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9189/the-word-believe-in-john-315-16); (which is admittedly very close), but pursues the dichotomy of believing "about Jesus", or "believing what he said."
2. [What is the difference between πιστεύων ἐν αὐτῷ and πιστεύων εἰς αὐτὸν?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/what-is-the-difference-between-%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%8D%CF%89%CE%BD-%E1%BC%90%CE%BD-%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%E1%BF%B7-and-%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%8D%CF%89%CE%BD-%CE%B5%E1%BC%B0%CF%82-%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%E1%BD%B8%CE%BD/9267#926) appears to be a survey, and juxtaposes "πιστεύων ἐν αὐτῷ" and "πιστεύων εἰς αὐτὸν",

Comment: Edited Question to focus on orgins, the rest is deferred to Susan's question: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/what-is-the-difference-between-%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%8D%CF%89%CE%BD-%E1%BC%90%CE%BD-%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%E1%BF%B7-and-%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%8D%CF%89%CE%BD-%CE%B5%E1%BC%B0%CF%82-%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%E1%BD%B8%CE%BD/18758#18758

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer your “Question 1”, as this is not addressed in the earlier question.

In Classical Greek πιστεύω means “trust, put faith in, rely on” and takes an object in the dative or accusative; it is never (as far as I can see) construed with the prepositions ἐν or εἰς. This construction is, however, commonplace in LXX and NT, e.g. Ps. 77:22, where ὅτι οὐκ ἐπίστευσαν ἐν τῷ θεῷ translates כִּי לֹא הֶאֱמִינוּ בֵּאלֹהִים quite literally (with ἐν for the preposition b-), "because they believed not in God" (KJV Ps. 78:22). I would think that this usage is a Semitism in Jewish koine.

Similarly Latin “credo” never takes the preposition “in” in the classical language, but “credo in + accusative” is commonplace in ecclesiastical Latin.

Comment: Not mentioned in the question, but does the same apply for πιστεύω + ἐπὶ? (Although that one isn’t used in the LXX for  –ב that I see; it only translates Is. 28:16 with no Hebrew correlate.)

Comment: For this too there are no classical examples in Liddell/Scott: http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.58:7:72.LSJ

Comment: Fascinating. Although ἐν is explained by the Hebrew, ἐπὶ and εἰς seem to be almost made up usages by the NT authors (plus Isaiah translator as above), but maybe that’s just overlapping prepositions (εἰς and ἐν at least).   (I think, by “this construction” you mean only πιστεύω + ἐν? πιστεύω + εἰς doesn’t seem to be in the LXX at all unless I missed it - in Ex 19:9 they’re juxtaposed but it’s not this construction.)

Comment: @Susan. Yes, I meant the construction with ἐν. Hebrew הֶאֱמִינ is construed both with b- and with l-, for which ἐν and εἰς respectively are the expected equivalents, and the same is true with Aramaic haymen.

Comment: @e.s.kohen. I am hesitant to read too much theology into this. In Semitic it is very ordinary to have a verb plus b- or l- where other languages have a transitive verb with direct object.

Comment: @fdb Thanks for the feedback, I removed the "Interpretation" portion of the question.  And I think the question Susan posted would be the correct place to address that.

Comment: @fdb It's been a while, but I have a related question to your answer.  Did the early fathers tackle this question? Does this occur in non-Biblical Hebrew/Aramaic tests, like Josephus, the Apocrypha, etc., (is it really exclusive to the NT)?  It seems odd that every New Testament book would adopt this wording format if there really wasn't a semantic significance behind it.  If "Greek Primacy" is assumed, I wouldn't think that Luke, or Romans, Acts, etc., would adopt this Semitism if their target audience had included the Greeks/Romans.  Wouldn't they wonder if it meant something special?

Answer (score 0):

When the result of a person's belief and trust and devotion to Christ is that God credits the person's faith as "righteous faith" then and only then does God transfer the person from being "in (within) Adam (the realm of darkness) into the kingdom of Christ.

Thus the difference is everything.  The second and third "soils" of Matthew 13 did not "believe into Him" but had believed superficially or had not made Christ their overriding priority.

Romans 4:4-5 and Romans 4:23-25 teach that God bestows blessings based on crediting a person with righteous faith, and among those blessings is justification, thus salvation.

It is this key aspect of salvation that is overlooked by translators who omit "into Him" in John 3:16.